# How to Hide this Box on blender

Tags: modeling

hello guys im Blender newbie here i would like to ask some question on how to delete this kind of box because i want to render image of viewport shading showing my model but this box is kinda ugly with it on my image result so is there a way to turn it off ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable all Overlays with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Or if you want to only disable a selection of overlays, look in the overlay menu either on the top right or bottom right of the 3D viewport. The grid is perspective view is the Floor. The Red,Green and Blue lines are the Axes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for the Help imma try it later thanks